# Convert jagged array to 2D array in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have two columns in a Google sheet: an ID column with a single value per cell and Color column with an arbitrary number of comma separated values per cell. I'd like to expand the Color column so each value is in its own cell, while retaining their associated IDs. This is illustrated in the attached image, and in this [worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q4Sg_ZbEYh8UhkIDj-KIH4ycEwmvkmPQnKmddiSVp_s/edit?usp=sharing).

I'm looking for a script or formulas to perform this operation on an array with ~30,000 rows. My clumsy solution (below and in second tab of worksheet) gives an error above about 1000 rows, as the length of a string made by join() is limited to 50,000 characters:

Create a list of repeated ID's with the same number of elements as as the list of colors in column C

```
=rept(A4&",",COUNTA(split(B4,", ",false)))
```

Concatenate each column then split each column:

```
=transpose(split(join(",",C4:C),",",false))  
=transpose(split(join(", ",B4:B),", ",false))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've clarified the question to specify that I need to process 30,000 rows.

Comment: Yes, Ruben, there could be spaces within the keywords in the color column, like 'light blue'. But I could work with a solution that didn't allow for this.

Comment: Does my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the OP example try the following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(
IFERROR(
REGEXEXTRACT(","&
TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
IFERROR(A4:A6&","&
REGEXEXTRACT(","&
SUBSTITUTE(B4:B6,", ",","),"^"&REPT(",+[^,]+",
COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,6))-1)&",+([^,]+)")&";")
,,1000))
,,1000),";"))),"^"&REPT(",+[^,]+",
COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,2))-1)&",+([^,]+)"
)
)
)
```

For the 30,000 rows:

- Change the references accordingly.
- Replace 1000 by 30000 or a larger number.

  - The 1000 is the headers argument of QUERY(data,query,[headers]). We want use a number big enough to include all the rows of the source data.
- If the second column of the source data has rows with more than 6 items, replace the 6 in OFFSET(A1,,,1,6) by the corresponding number of items.

See the reference for further details.

## References

[JOINing code-points after CHAR conversion in Google Spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97840/joining-code-points-after-char-conversion-in-google-spreadsheets/97911)